# For an element with infinite order, how many generators does $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ have

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

> Question: Let a be an element of a group and suppose that *a* has infinite order. How many generators does $\left \langle a \right \rangle$ have?

Following from the hypothesis that *a* has infinite order, distinct power on *a* are distinct group elements.

A bit of a brick wall here.

Only hints are appreciated unless it involves substantial number theory.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Said differently, for the subgroup $H = <1>$ of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ what is the subgroup of $H$ generated by the element $1\,?$

Comment: One more hint: What is the _definition_ (in words) of $<1>$?

Comment: $1 \in \mathbb{Z} so \left \langle 1 \right \rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of the group $\left ( \mathbb{Z},+ \right )$. 
In fact, $\left \langle 1 \right \rangle = \left ( \mathbb{Z},+ \right ) $so$ \left ( \mathbb{Z},+ \right )$ is a cyclic group. 
To determine the generators of cyclic groups we recall:
G=$\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle$ IFF$ gcd\left ( n,k \right )=1$
@bof

Comment: @quasi 
$\left \langle 1 \right \rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup generated by the element 1 in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Ok, so is the element $1$ a generator of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$?

Comment: @quasi of course it is.
Observe: 
$\left \langle 1 \right \rangle = \left \{ 1^{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right \}=\left \{\cdot \cdot \cdot ,-3,-2,-1 ,e, 1, 2, 3,\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}=\left ( \mathbb{Z},+ \right )$

Comment: Is the element $2$ a generator of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$?

Comment: It is not. 
Observe: $3 \in \mathbb{Z} but \left \langle 2 \right \rangle = \left \{\cdot \cdot \cdot , -6,-4,-2,e,+2,+4,+6,\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right \}\nsupseteq 3$@quasi

Comment: Is there any other integer that will generate $(\mathbb{Z},+)$?

Comment: @quasi -1 would. 
In fact, there are two generators; 1 and -1.

Comment: Now you got it.

Comment: A notational comment: For $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, the identity element is $0$, so calling it $e$ is not necessary (and not usually done).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $b=a^k$ is a generator of the subgroup $<a>$. Then, as as $a\in<a>$, there must be $l\in\mathbb N^\ast$ such that $b^l=a$.

But then $(a^k)^l=a$, so $a^{kl-1}=e$ ($e$ unit element). What does this say about $a$, or $k$ ?

Comment: *a* has infinite order implies there exists no (least) positive integer n such that $a^{n}=e$.

So $a^{kl-1}=e$ implies that kl-1=0
Thus, kl=1

Comment: Your ending is right :-)

Comment: How does this leads me to conclude anything about the number of generators for $\left \langle a \right \rangle$?

Comment: $kl=1$ and $k$ and $l$ being integers means $k=l=1$. So $b$ is a generator iff $b=a$ : so there is exactly one generator...

Comment: Well, in fact, $2$, because there is also the solution $k=l=-1$ :-)

Comment: Aha! Didn't saw that coming.